# URP Camera Stacking. Different intensity of bloom in different objects

Tags: unity, post-processing, unity-urp, bloom

I understand that this topic has been raised more than once, but I have not found detailed step-by-step instructions anywhere on how to do this.

1. Install the Universal RP and Post Processing packages.
2. Create URP Asset (with Universal Renderer). In the project settings in Scriptable Render Papeline Settings I select New URP Asset.
3. Then I add two gameobject cube Intensity1, intensity2 to the scene. Next creating an material emission HDR White color . I install it on cubes.
4. I create two empty gameobject bloom1, bloom2 and add the volume component to them, add a new bloom profile to the volume.
5. I add two layers bloom1, bloom2, I place one cube on the bloom1 layer, the other on bloom2. I do the same with volume.
6. I create a new camera render type set to overlay, Culling mask bloom1. The first camera's render type is base, culling mask bloom2.
7. Both cameras post processing check box enabled.
8. I add a new camera to the stack of the first camera.
   I'm doing something wrong somewhere, so only one volume works for all objects at once. Maybe someone saw a working instruction for this feature? Or maybe someone can correct my steps?

Comment: Remember that bloom is a post process. It applies to everything on the screen after rendering has finished. By the time the second camera has rendered, that's... everything. So this strategy cannot exclude any objects from the second bloom. There may be easier ways to achieve this is effect, if you can show us examples of the objects you want to render and how they should differ in bloom.

Comment: There are two white cubes with emission material. I need to be able to individually regulate the intensity of bloom of each of them.